# Convert date in dd/MM/yyyy and store it in DateTime object

Tags: c#, .net, date, parsing, datetime

In my website I am uploading an .xls file and fetching data from it using third party tool Aspose. I want date in dd/MM/yyyy format and using below functionality for this.

```
string dt = "24/01/2013";
DateTime dd = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but after conversion date is not in specified format (dd/MM/yyyy) it is in MM/dd/yyyy format.

Can any one suggest me what am I doing wrong or can suggest some other way.

Thank You.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. What you think is a format, is just how the debugger displays the variable's content.

Comment: How do you output the parsed date? Is it possible that the parsing is as desired, but the output is localized in an different way than you expect?

Comment: Formats apply only when you convert dates from/to strings. Change the culture or the format string in your report/view/control to get the string you want

Answer (score 2):

DateTime doesn't have a specific format. It's up to you to specify the format when you try to build a string within. For what you need :

```
string formattedDate = dd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date is ok. If not, there will be an exception. To convert date to string in specific format (and check that parsing was correct) write:

```
string dt = "24/01/2013";
DateTime dd = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string dt1 = dd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
if (dt == dt1)
    Console.WriteLine("All ok!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Something was wrong!");
```